# How can I assign the result of an addition of floats to a register variable?

Tags: vim

I try to assign the result of an addition to a register variable

```
:let @a=40-39995.96
```

and get a `E806: using Float as a String` error. How can I omit this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can convert the result of the expression into string, using `string(expr)`

```
let @a=string(40-39995.96)
```

check this too:

```
:h string()
```